# Insert statement not working

Tags: c#

I'm creating a small  c# application using VS local database these are my commands for inserting its not showing any error but the fields are not inserted in the database.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{            
    SqlCeConnection cn=new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.sdf");

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cn.Open();
        SqlCeCommand cmd;
        string sql = "insert into sales values (@item, @price)";
        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, cn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", "7777");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price"," 2");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Just one more question when deploying this application to the user should I install anything on the client machine??

Comment: what does cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); return?

Comment: how to check what does it return, sry but I'm really new

Comment: @zozi `var whatever = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: your sql syntax is invalid.  Also you should wrap your `SqlCeConnection` and `SqlCeCommand` in using statements

Comment: @zozi, you should be using `using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand (sql, cn))` and the same for SqlCeConnection. This will auto dispose and auto close the connection, no need for the finally statement

Comment: `Data Source=|DataDirectory|`  You are probably not looking at the right database, but a copy.

Comment: The first form does not specify the column names where the data will be inserted, only their values:

INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
The second form specifies both the column names and the values to be inserted:

INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...); I would specify the column names personally just to be safe make sure your connection string is also valid check this link for proper ways to do conn string in sql server 
[C# Connectionstrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com)

Comment: @Kritner its giving 1

Comment: @zozi sounds like it's working to me.  Are you sure you're checking that it "didn't work" on the same database your query is executing on?

Comment: just a question If I'm using VS local db (.sdf) extension how can I install it to the client?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
  //include column names
  string sql = "insert into sales(Item,Price) values (@item, @price)";

   try
   {
     cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, cn);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", 7777); //int instead of string
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", 2); //int instead of string
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
```